# Convert Switch to if-else statement automatically

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree

I am developing a plug-in in `Eclipse` and I have to process the source code of a Java class to generate a `JSON` file. I use the Java `AST` framework to do the process of converting java code into `JSON` code.

I am writing this question because I do not know if there is some external or internal tool of `Eclipse` that allows to convert `switch` into `if-else` statement. I want to do this conversion because I am capable of processing `if-else` statements, therefore, having the conversion desired I would process the `switch` statement as `if-else` statement.

Any suggestion or idea is well received. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it helps, `ctrl + 1` is a keyboard shortcut that may be of use.

Comment: Add handling of switch statements to your AST walker.

Comment: You are right @notyou, but if  ``switch`` statement does not have ``break`` statement, that shortcut does not work. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: What I am looking for @FrankC. is something that allows me to convert ``switch`` statement into ``if-else`` statement in an easy way. E.g. some external tool, some internal tool of Eclipse, etc.

Comment: I looked, and cannot find any tool to support conversion if any `case` condition (except `default`) lacks a `break`. It's also worth noting that Intellij IDEA behaves the same way as `ctrl + 1` in Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you so much @skomisa. I am afraid that I wiil have to implement that conversion xD.